# Undefined subroutines &main error in Perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, subroutine, fasta

I am trying to extract a DNA sequence from this FASTA file to a specified length of bases per line, say 40.

```
> sample dna  (This is a typical fasta header.)
agatggcggcgctgaggggtcttgggggctctaggccggccacctactgg
tttgcagcggagacgacgcatggggcctgcgcaataggagtacgctgcct
gggaggcgtgactagaagcggaagtagttgtgggcgcctttgcaaccgcc
tgggacgccgccgagtggtctgtgcaggttcgcgggtcgctggcgggggt
```

Using this Perl module (fasta.pm):

```
package fasta;
use strict;

sub read_fasta ($filename) {
    my $filename = @_;
    open (my $FH_IN, "<", $filename) or die "Can't open file: $filename $!";
    my @lines = <$FH_IN>;
    chomp @lines;
    return @lines;
}

sub read_seq (\@lines) {
    my $linesRef = @_;
    my @lines = @{$linesRef};
    my @seq;
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        if ($line!~ /^>/) {
            print "$line\n";
            push (@seq, $line);
        }
    }
    return @seq;
}

sub print_seq_40 (\@seq) {
    my $linesRef = @_;
    my @lines = @{$linesRef};
    my $seq;
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        $seq = $seq.$line;
    }

    my $i= 0;
    my $seq_line;
    while (($i+1)*40 < length ($seq)) {
        my $seq_line = substr ($seq, $i*40, 40);
        print "$seq_line\n";
        $i++;
    }
    $seq_line = substr ($seq, $i*40);
    print "$seq_line\n";
}
1;
```

And the main script is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use fasta;

print "What is your filename: ";
my $filename = <STDIN>;
chomp $filename;

my @lines = read_fasta ($filename);
my @seq = read_seq (\@lines);
print_seq_40 (\@seq);
exit;
```

This is the error I get

```
Undefined subroutine &main::read_fasta called at q2.pl line 13, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Can anyone please enlighten me on which part I did wrong?

Comment: You need to either prefix your calls to functions in fasta.pm with "fasta::" - i.e. write fasta::read_fasta($filename) etc. - or you need to change fasta.pm to export the function you want to be available without the prefix.

Comment: Usually only Perls own packages start with a lower-case character, so you may want to rename your .pm.

Comment: Finally, taking a look at BioPerl for parsing/generating bioinformatics related formats might be worth your while: http://bioperl.org/

Comment: the last part should work, though. Calling explicitly with Fasta:: works and always has worked for me. Please post specific error message for that.

Comment: The error message for the Fasta:: part is updated in the post

Comment: just use my sub declaration, I edited. Similar for other subs.

Comment: What you were doing was trying to use perl prototypes. I would suggest you don't. If you want users to know what to put in, make a comment, pod or similar, this is not supported well ( regarding `sub method ( $arg ){` )

Comment: I updated my current main script and Fasta.pm. Still getting the Undefined subroutine &main error. And if I add a Fasta:: prefix in the main script I get error saying that I dont have enough argument

Comment: Where did `Fasta.pm` come from? There are severe problems with it that need to be fixed.

Comment: *Please* don't keep editing your question to include advice that people have given you: it makes nonsense of the answers and comments.

Comment: you ignored me. `sub read_fasta { my $filename = @_;` is not working. I told you to just follow my example in the answer that I edited in. This is not so in your post.

Comment: I wrote it, may I know the whats the problems

Comment: @bytepusher I did follow I updated in my post. I didn't know I shouldn't keep editing my post as suggested by Borodin

Comment: well, I updated to include `our @ISA = qw( Exporter );` which is needed. Sorry. I also edited in an explanation for why $scalar =@_ is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're getting nowhere with this.

I think your choice to use a module and subroutines is a little strange, given that you call each subroutine only once and the correspond to very little code indeed.

Both your program and your module need to start with `use strict` and `use warnings`, and you cannot use prototypes like that in Perl subroutines. Including a number of other bugs, this is a lot closer to the code that you need.

```
package Fasta;

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use base 'Exporter';

our @EXPORT = qw/ read_fasta read_seq print_seq_40 /;

sub read_fasta {
  my ($filename) = @_;

  open my $fh_in, '<', $filename;
  chomp(my @lines = <$fh_in>);

  @lines;
}

sub read_seq {
  my ($lines_ref) = $_[0];

  grep { not /^>/ } @$lines_ref;
}

sub print_seq_40 {
  my ($lines_ref) = @_;

  print "$_\n" for unpack '(A40)*', join '', @$lines_ref;
}

1;
```

**q2.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Fasta qw/ read_fasta read_seq print_seq_40 /;

print "What is your filename: ";
my $filename = <STDIN>;
chomp $filename;

my @lines = read_fasta($filename);
my @seq = read_seq(\@lines);
print_seq_40(\@seq);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, if you `use fasta;`, this does not automatically export all its methods into the namespace of your program. Call fasta::read_fasta instead.

Or: use [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) to automatically export methods or enable something like `use Fasta qw/read_fasta/`.

For example:

```
package Fasta;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/read_fasta read_seq read_seq40/;
```

To use:

```
use Fasta qw/read_fasta read_seq read_seq40/;
```

You can also make Fasta export all methods automatically or define keywords to group methods, though the latter has caused me some problems in the past, and I would recommend it only if you are certain it is worth possible trouble.

If you want to make all methods available:

```
package Fasta;
use Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw/read_fasta read_seq read_seq40/;
```

Note @EXPORT is not @EXPORT_OK. The latter allows importing them later (as I did), the former automatically exports all. The documentation I linked to makes this clear.

I just noticed something else. You are flattening @_ into $filename in read_fasta. I am not sure this works. Try this:

```
sub read_fasta {
   my $filename = $_[0]; # or ($filename) = @_; @_ is an array. $filename not.
}
```

To explain the problem: `$filename = @_;` means: store @_ ( an ARRAY ) into $filename (a SCALAR). Perl does this in this way: ARRAY length is stored in $filename. That is not what you want. You want the first element of the array. That would be $_[0].

Added @ISA which is probably needed OR use comment by Borodir.

Comment: I tried using Exporter but still giving the same error. Updated in my post.

Comment: use `@EXPORT_OK` or `@EXPORT`. Import accordingly. I updated my answer to include the `@EXPORT` method.

Comment: I followed exactly your suggestion in pm file and the main script but still receiving the error. Both files are in the same directory and I renamed fasta.pm to Fasta.pm. Could it be other cause for this error?

Comment: try with `our @EXPORT_OK`, I took it without from the docs, but I usually do it that way. Also, the newline after Fasta confused me, why did you put that there :/ Just to be sure: the package name and file must be identical, always.

Comment: This is misleading. You need to add `Exporter` to the `@ISA` array as well, so `use base 'Exporter'` is better than `require`. In addition, the subroutine prototypes are incorrect, and the module should start `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: good point: where is @ISA? like I said above, skip the prototypes or learn to use them. I do not see why skipping should not work.

Comment: For pretty much every practical purpose you should heavily discourage the use of subroutine prototypes. Also, an answer on Stack Overflow should be a self-contained solution, not an ongoing dialogue where you and the OP amend your posts incrementally. Remember that the primary and overriding purpose of Stack Overflow is to form a reference of common programming problems and thrir solutions. If an answer is of no use to anyone but the OP then it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: alright, perhaps I did not discourage heavily enough. Regarding the second: I agree and will do so in future, I used to do it better anyhow. Apart from my oversight, it is a function of the question being amended. I regret getting started with this anyhow :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to either:

- add to your module:

  ```
  use Exporter;
  our @EXPORT = qw ( read_fasta
                     read_seq ); #etc.
  ```
- call the code in the remote module explicitly:

  ```
  fasta::read_fasta();
  ```
- explicitly import the module sub:

  ```
  use fasta qw ( read_fasta );
  ```

Also: General convention on modules is to uppercase the first letter of the module name.

Comment: I tried some of the suggestion but still it doesn't work. Updated in the post.

Comment: Ah yes. Upon looking again, your function definitions are incorrect. Lose the prototyping, and if you're assigning something off `@_` you need to do it in a list context. E.g. `my ( $lines_ref ) = @_;` - otherwise it'll only end up being a count of the elements in `@_`